# Getting the total message queue size in Erlang/Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm building some monitoring for an Elixir app and want to be tracking the total length of process' message queues - if they go over any reasonable value it would mean the system isn't keeping up.

How would one query in a real-life system? [`:erlang.system_info/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info-1) doesn't seem to be providing it, and you can only get per-process information from [`:erlang.process_info/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-1). I don't like the idea of using the latter and manually aggregating the message queue lengths, since there's potentially thousands of relevant GenServer processes and instrumenting them feels like unnecessary overhead.

I seem to remember [Wombat OAM](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/products/wombat-oam.html) having this functionality which makes me think it's possible, but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang:

All info: `:erlang.process_info(self())`

Just the message queue length: `:erlang.process_info(self(), :message_queue_len)` # => `{:message_queue_len, 2}`

Just the messages: `:erlang.process_info(self(), :messages)` #=> `{:messages, [:hello, :world]}`

---

In Elixir:

All the info: `Process.info(self())`

Just the message queue length: `Process.info(self(), :message_queue_len)`

Just the messages: `Process.info(self(), :messages)`

Both give the same output which includes

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for - I even mentioned the functions you're suggesting that I use. I'm looking for a way to get the sum of message queue lengths for all processes in the system, not per-process.

Answer (score 1):

For Erlang, I would recommend you using [recon](https://github.com/ferd/recon).

In Elixir, there is a wrapper to it: [tap](https://github.com/eproxus/tap).

I would also suggest reading  [Stuff Goes Bad Erlang in Anger](https://www.erlang-in-anger.com/) .

Comment: I might be missing things, but I don't think recon offers that functionality either, and tap is just a wrapper for recon tracing, which I think is irrelevant to that question. I didn't have a chance to read the "Stuff Goes Bad - Erlang in Anger" book yet, I'll see what it adds soon.